# Estimate gas from within smart contract

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, axelar

Let's assume that a smart contract A is deployed in Moonbeam and a smart contract B is deployed in Binance Smart Chain.

Contract A sends transactions to contract B and vice versa like a ping-pong game.
As long as both contracts A and B can estimate Gas accurately they can keep playing ping-pong until they run out of funds

Question: Is there a way to safely estimate gas from within sc A before sending the tx to scB?

Note: I am aware of how to `estimateGasFee` from front end using Axelar JS SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the `estimateGasFee` method provided by the [Axelar JS SDK](https://docs.axelar.dev/dev/axelarjs-sdk/axelar-query-api#estimategasfee). However,  there is no direct way to estimate gas fees within a smart contract itself.

Since the transaction is going through the Axelar network -> destination chain and your solidity code only has access to data about the source chain, we can only access data via the Axelarjs SDK, not natively in your solidity code.